# Scala: late side effect initialisation

Tags: scala

If I want late initialisation of an expression, I can use a lazy val. But what can I use to to do late side effect initialisation?

I want to do things like creating a menubar in a base class. The actual content of the menus are finalised in API independent traits, which are mixed into sub classes of the API dependant base class. Early initialisation does not work, because there are multiple vals that would have to be early initialised in every sub class.

Another alternative is to create a procedure and call it in the constructors of all the final sub classes. But this is still inelegant and not DRY.

Edit: I don't think Delayed Init will work, as far as I understand it because that will put the whole constructor /initialisation code into a delayed method , and I need to put only part of it at the end of the construction process.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I get the question right, but perhaps you could do something like this:

```
abstract class AbstractFoo {

  lazy val menuBar = computeMenuBar

  def menuBar: MenuBar

}

class ConcreteFoo extends AbstractFoo {

  def menuBar: MenuBar = MenuBar("One", "Two")

}
```